# How can one run many copies of a MacOS App

Tags: macos, operating-system, virtual-machine

I was thinking of this today and was wondering what is it on MacOS app that prevent me from running, for example, 5 instances of a specific app?

I was thinking it could be the bundle_id (similar to iOS) but when I copied and renamed the app (to appname_2) edited the bundle_id (to bundle_id_2) for that specific app it didn't launch and instead just put that application in the foreground.

Maybe there's a method that checks the Mac address of the device and only allows one app to run per Mac address.

Due to it being hard to find and info on this online, wondering if it's possible to run multiple versions of an app on my Mac.

I'm pretty sure a virtual machine would work but if I wanted to run 100 instances of that specific app then id run all out of ram and would render my Mac useless for actual work.

Answer (score 1):

The LaunchServices (Finder, NSWorkspace APIs, etc.) on MacOS allow you run one app per user session. Nothing prevents you from launching an app a second time when you don't use Launch Services. (And your assumption is correct that LaunchServices looks at the BundleID to see if the app is already running).

e.g. when you open two Terminal windows and start Mail via (`/Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail`) in both you have two Mail instances. `open /Applications/Mail.app/` won't work two times because it'll use LaunchServices.

Comment: is there a way to prevent launch services for a specific app? any blog post you recommend?

Comment: I've been trying to do this to run a certain app 

/Applications/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp &

And get Programm already running then it exits - are there any solutions to bypass that?

Comment: @stringRay2014 how does it exit? I this case the program (probably) does have it's own additional check.